# R: given a list of dataframes, rbind all but one of them

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind, do.call

Set-up to problem: I want to subset my 500-row dataframe into 10 subsets of 50 rows each.  Then I want to use 9 of them as a training set and 1 as a test in such a way that each subset gets one "chance" to be the test data.

What I have done so far:

```
# Get my 10 equal subsets and convert each to a data matrix.  
b <- seq(50, 500, 50)
subsets <- lapply(seq_along(b), function(i) trainN[(b-49)[i]:b[i], ])
subsetsDF <- lapply(subsets, data.matrix)
# subsetsDF is a list of 10 data matrices
```

What I cannot do: 
I do not know how to loop over the data matrix indices from i=1 to 10, using index i as test data and rbinding the rest and assigning it to "train data"  My attempt so far:

```
function(data) {
   n_subset <- 1:10
   for(j in seq_along(n_subset)) {
      test <- data[[j]]
      #train <- do.call(rbind, data[[-j]]) of course this isn't right
   }
}
```

Note: I welcome any suggestions that completely restructure my approach.  As I reflect on what I'm trying to do, it occurs that this is not the best way.  Nonetheless, the posed question still interests me.  So I welcome both answers that strictly address my question as well as answers that offer a better approach.  (For example, I know for loops are not efficient in R...I don't know how to do this with apply functions.  After I complete this, I need to nest it within another function that runs the 10 different models resulting from the different test/train divisions on each of several values for k.)

Comment: Have you tried `data[-j]` instead?

Comment: Huh. That works.  I over-complicate everything!  So, as for why it works: is that because "-j" refers to multiple elements (whereas "j" is just one list)?

Comment: So it's the difference between `[` and `[[` which do different things: `[[` always selects a single element, whereas `[` select the sub-list. One analogy I've seen is that if a list is a sequence of train cars, `[[` selects the _contents_ of a single train car, whereas `[` select a subset of train cars themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That's so clear now.  I don't know what to do with this question now though; do you want to submit that as the answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Now that we've confirmed that that really is what the issue was, it's easier to just have this question point to a decent duplicate.